# How to add index to increase speed of mysql statement

Tags: mysql, time

How do I increase the speed of this mysql statement? taking 1.10s but was wondering if it could be made faster.

```
SELECT 
        res_rooms.room_id AS room,
        res_rooms.type AS room_type,
        res_rooms.status AS room_status,
        IFNULL(utilizations.user_id, - 1) AS user_id,
        CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.surname, camps.s_surname) AS surname,
        CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.name, camps.s_first) AS name,
        IFNULL(utilizations.start_date, NULL) AS start_date,
        IFNULL(utilizations.end_date, NULL) AS end_date,
        utilizations.keys_issued AS keys_issued,
        utilizations.resource_type AS resource_type,
        utilizations.staff_id AS staff_id,
        CONCAT_WS(0, students.handled_by, camps.handled_by) AS handled_by,
        CONCAT_WS(0,
                students.date_of_birth,
                camps.date_of_birth) AS dob,
        CONCAT_WS(0, students.gender, camps.sex) AS gender,
        CONCAT_WS(0, students.status, camps.status) AS status,
        countries.common_name AS citizenship,
        CONCAT_WS(0, students.applying_for, camps.applying) AS applying_for,
        IFNULL(fee_schedule.ResiLife_type, 'N/A') AS residence_type,
        IFNULL(fee_schedule.Resi_Amount, 'N/A') AS reslife_amount
    FROM
        res_rooms
            LEFT JOIN
        utilizations ON utilizations.resource_id = res_rooms.room_id
            LEFT JOIN
        system_users ON system_users.user_id = utilizations.user_id
            LEFT JOIN
        camps ON camps.camp_id = utilizations.user_id
            LEFT JOIN
        students ON students.user_id = utilizations.user_id
            LEFT JOIN
        countries ON (students.citizenship = countries.code
            || camps.citizenship = countries.code)
            LEFT JOIN
        fee_schedule ON utilizations.user_id = fee_schedule.Stud_id
    WHERE
        (students.status = 'B'
            OR students.status = 'VC')
            AND utilizations.start_date <= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY room_id , start_date DESC
```

When using `Explain`:

[image]

Stats of the query:

[image]

Comment: Most of the `LEFT JOIN`s actually return an `INNER JOIN` result due to the WHERE-conditions. And an `OR`ed join is usually quite bad. Try repalcing it by ´UNION`ing two Selects (copy the Select and use one of the join conditions to `countries`.

Comment: could you explain this more?

Comment: Adding more information to the question would help us help you. In particular: the total number of rows you get when you run the query as is; table and index definitions for the tables involved (if not full table definitions, then at least the critical columns - primary key, any foreign keys); if possible, the query plan used when the query is run (check [docs on `EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for how to do this).

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; sounds like the indexes or datatypes are 'bad'.

Comment: Do I do this for all tables? or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an indexes for each table having `NULL` in the  `possible_keys` of `EXPLAIN`. Columns used for index should be the same used for `JOIN`s. In case of `countries` table you have to add an index for `code` field while corresponding tables `students` and `camps` should be indexed on the `citizenship` fields each.

The common rule is:

When you join two tables with `ON` condition, each table should have indexed columns used for `ON`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.foo = b.bar;
```

Here table `a` should have index (foo) while table `b` should have index (bar)

When you filter out rows by `WHERE` clause, columns mentioned in the `WHERE` conditions should be indexed:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM a
 WHERE a.foo = 1234;
```

Here table `a` should have index (foo).

Complex conditions that refers to the multiple columns in the same table require multicolumn indexes:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM a
 WHERE a.foo = 1234
   AND a.bar BETWEEN '2017-07-20' AND '2017-07-21';
```

Here table `a` should have an multicolumn index (foo, bar) or (bar,foo), or even  both. It's depends on certain data stored in your table and some performance measurements should be performed. Even though for different queries different indexes can become optimal and day-wide range could be faster with (foo,bar) while month-wide range could be faster with (bar,foo).

Comment: Do I add indexes for all columns of tables that are NULL in the possible_keys of EXPLAIN?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Is it possible the query cant be made faster?

Comment: I got it working. Finally understanding where i need to use indexes too. Thanks. I'll award bounty in 22 hours when I can!

Comment: The main sign of the problem is the `using filesort` message in the `EXPLAIN`s output. You can have some indexes for all the tables but if some of them are inappropriate for certain query you'll end up with performance losses. Avoid `Using filesort` at any cost because that drive to the creation of huge on-disk tempopary tables that are slow.

Comment: How would I prevent using it?

Comment: Supply every `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUB BY` and `ORDER BY` clause by appropriate index(es).  That can't be automated but `EXPLAIN` gives enough information to make a decision. Do not create every possible index in advance because every index need some resources to be maintained. Especially multicolumn indexes. Some practice and you'll see the woman in red.

Comment: Alright one last question. Can I create index for columns from separate tables. For example, for ORDER BY room_id , start_date DESC, where room_id and start_date are from different tables

Answer (score 1):

The joins to `utilizations` and `students` are actually Inner Join as the WHERE-conditions will remove the NULLs created by the Outer Join.

The join to `countries` is really bad as it's using an `OR`ed condition and joins three tables at the same time (optmizers choke on that).

Switch to Inner Joins whenever possible (MySQL's optimizer used to be bad in recognizing that an Outer Join is actually a Inner).

And try replacing the `OR`ed join with `UNION`:

```
SELECT 
    res_rooms.room_id AS room,
    res_rooms.type AS room_type,
    res_rooms.status AS room_status,
    IFNULL(utilizations.user_id, - 1) AS user_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.surname, camps.s_surname) AS surname,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.name, camps.s_first) AS name,
    IFNULL(utilizations.start_date, NULL) AS start_date,
    IFNULL(utilizations.end_date, NULL) AS end_date,
    utilizations.keys_issued AS keys_issued,
    utilizations.resource_type AS resource_type,
    utilizations.staff_id AS staff_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.handled_by, camps.handled_by) AS handled_by,
    CONCAT_WS(0,
            students.date_of_birth,
            camps.date_of_birth) AS dob,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.gender, camps.sex) AS gender,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.status, camps.status) AS status,
    countries.common_name AS citizenship,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.applying_for, camps.applying) AS applying_for,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.ResiLife_type, 'N/A') AS residence_type,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.Resi_Amount, 'N/A') AS reslife_amount
FROM
    res_rooms
        JOIN
    utilizations ON utilizations.resource_id = res_rooms.room_id
        LEFT JOIN
    system_users ON system_users.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    camps ON camps.camp_id = utilizations.user_id
        JOIN
    students ON students.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    countries ON students.citizenship = countries.code
        LEFT JOIN
    fee_schedule ON utilizations.user_id = fee_schedule.Stud_id
WHERE
    (students.status = 'B'
        OR students.status = 'VC')
        AND utilizations.start_date <= CURDATE()

UNION

SELECT 
    res_rooms.room_id AS room,
    res_rooms.type AS room_type,
    res_rooms.status AS room_status,
    IFNULL(utilizations.user_id, - 1) AS user_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.surname, camps.s_surname) AS surname,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.name, camps.s_first) AS name,
    IFNULL(utilizations.start_date, NULL) AS start_date,
    IFNULL(utilizations.end_date, NULL) AS end_date,
    utilizations.keys_issued AS keys_issued,
    utilizations.resource_type AS resource_type,
    utilizations.staff_id AS staff_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.handled_by, camps.handled_by) AS handled_by,
    CONCAT_WS(0,
            students.date_of_birth,
            camps.date_of_birth) AS dob,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.gender, camps.sex) AS gender,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.status, camps.status) AS status,
    countries.common_name AS citizenship,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.applying_for, camps.applying) AS applying_for,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.ResiLife_type, 'N/A') AS residence_type,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.Resi_Amount, 'N/A') AS reslife_amount
FROM
    res_rooms
        JOIN
    utilizations ON utilizations.resource_id = res_rooms.room_id
        LEFT JOIN
    system_users ON system_users.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    camps ON camps.camp_id = utilizations.user_id
        JOIN
    students ON students.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    countries ON camps.citizenship = countries.code
        LEFT JOIN
    fee_schedule ON utilizations.user_id = fee_schedule.Stud_id
WHERE
    (students.status = 'B'
        OR students.status = 'VC')
        AND utilizations.start_date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY room_id , start_date DESC
```

Or maybe better replace it by two joins to `countries` plus `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    res_rooms.room_id AS room,
    res_rooms.type AS room_type,
    res_rooms.status AS room_status,
    IFNULL(utilizations.user_id, - 1) AS user_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.surname, camps.s_surname) AS surname,
    CONCAT_WS(0, system_users.name, camps.s_first) AS name,
    IFNULL(utilizations.start_date, NULL) AS start_date,
    IFNULL(utilizations.end_date, NULL) AS end_date,
    utilizations.keys_issued AS keys_issued,
    utilizations.resource_type AS resource_type,
    utilizations.staff_id AS staff_id,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.handled_by, camps.handled_by) AS handled_by,
    CONCAT_WS(0,
            students.date_of_birth,
            camps.date_of_birth) AS dob,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.gender, camps.sex) AS gender,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.status, camps.status) AS status,
    COALESCE(c1.common_name, c2.common_name) AS citizenship,
    CONCAT_WS(0, students.applying_for, camps.applying) AS applying_for,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.ResiLife_type, 'N/A') AS residence_type,
    IFNULL(fee_schedule.Resi_Amount, 'N/A') AS reslife_amount
FROM
    res_rooms
        JOIN
    utilizations ON utilizations.resource_id = res_rooms.room_id
        LEFT JOIN
    system_users ON system_users.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    camps ON camps.camp_id = utilizations.user_id
        JOIN
    students ON students.user_id = utilizations.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    countries AS c1 ON students.citizenship = c1.code
        LEFT JOIN
    countries AS c2 ON camps.citizenship = c2.code
        LEFT JOIN
    fee_schedule ON utilizations.user_id = fee_schedule.Stud_id
WHERE
    (students.status = 'B'
        OR students.status = 'VC')
        AND utilizations.start_date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY room_id , start_date DESC
```

Comment: makes it slower

Comment: Which one, both? Then you might check if you got the right indexes.

Comment: the first one is around 1.9s and the second is about 1.2s. And I tried adding indexes but not sure if I did it right.

Comment: So this doesn't seem to be related to the actual SQL, but indexing (or the actual size of the tables). To facilitate the joins the join columns are usualy indexed and the columns in `WHERE`

Comment: Anything I can read for this? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL guy, there are lots of online resources, e.g. http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Note that both the student and the camp could tie to a country. If they tie to different countries, you'll get two country records for that student (and thus two result rows for the student) in your original query, and in the `UNION ALL`. The query that `COALESCE`s the country names resolves that problem.

Comment: @dnoeth `MySQL` in fact have only three types of joins - natural/cartesian, inner `JOIN...ON` and `LEFT JOIN`. All the rest are just derivatives or syntax sugar ones,

Comment: @Kondybas: Did I say anything about join types (btw, `natural join` is not a join type)? I just claimed that some Outer Joins in the OP are actually returning the result of an Inner Join and he should fix that (or double check if the result is actually the expected one)